# Is it legal to teach about hacking and tools?

Tags: legal, professional-education, tools, user-education

I'am currentliy working on a e-learning content about wireless security.
It is an app I want to launch on the AppStore and Google Play.
It shows what the problems and dangers are and also what tools hacker use with an explanation how they work. So the actual commands are shown and the tools are demonstrated in a video.

Could there be a legal problem in some countries talking about the tools, naming and demonstrating them?

Comment: You are indeed putting yourself and others at risk at a certain level so you should consult with a lawyer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks a purely legal question. While there probably will be opinions here about this topic they are usually based on what can be found in the media and which do not necessarily reflect the actual laws, which may also be different between countries. Thus a better forum would be law.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, different parts of the world have different laws, and no doubt some of the more hardline states may take a dim view of someone purposefully guiding someone on how to 'hack'.

Your question is very open and contains many variables, for example; if you could be seen as providing material support to terrorists in some western countries if the wrong person makes use of your information. (Although I am unsure of any cases when this has occurred)

Additionally, there are many tutorials and guides online on how to 'hack' that are perfectly legal and will probably never be in any threat from legal action.

The main thing to consider is not what you are writing about, but the intent of what you're writing for. If you write with a clear intent to break the law or support someone breaking the law, then you may find yourself in trouble.

Fundamentally, in most western countries it is not illegal to write about hacking tools, to develop hacking tools or to use hacking tools. As long as you don't break the law or provide support for someone else to break the law.

[Have a look at the Wikipedia article on Bomb-making instructions on the internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bomb-making_instructions_on_the_internet), as there are some parallels, and it goes some way to explaining the gray area of this.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll better black out the command names then. I just want the people to know how easy it can be to get in wireless networks and provide a guide to protect themself.